# Identify Minimum Value Within Group and Set Column Equal to A Different Column For That Row Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Hard to describe without showing an example, but I'd like to create a column in my pandas dataframe where the value is equal to the value of a different column based on the minimum of another column in a group.

Let's say I have the following dataframe:

[image]

My goal here is to create a new column 'd' that is equal to the value in c, however I want it to equal the minimum of 'a' for each value of 'b'.

Below is the desired dataframe:

[image]

Comment: Why ```dog``` got ```9```, shouldn't it be ```8```?

Comment: Please include your sample/expected data as text, not pictures.

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski because 2 is the minimum of col `a` (for group 'dog') ... OP needs value from c from that row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`idxmin` is what you are looking for:

```
 df['d'] = df.loc[df.groupby('b')['a'].transform('idxmin'), 'c'].values
```

Output:

```
      a    b   c  d
0     1  cat   5  5
1   334  cat   6  5
2   321  cat   7  5
3     3  dog   8  9
4     2  dog   9  9
5   232  dog  10  9
6  3123  dog  11  9
```

Comment: This answer seems to be simplest.

Answer (score 4):

use:

```
df['d'] = (df.sort_values(['b','a'])['c']
             .where(df['a'].eq(df.groupby('b')['a'].transform('min'))).ffill())
```